# join list of dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I have a list of *macaddresses* and *network adapters* that I'd like to combine into single list.

```yaml
  vars:
    network_adapters:
    - name: "Network adapter one"
    - name: "Network adapter two"

    macaddresses:
    - "00:50:56:9c:8c:b1"
    - "00:50:56:9c:8c:b2"
```

It can be done with below method using additional variable but I'm hoping for **oneliner**.

```yaml
  - name: "Set fact"
    set_fact:
      network_interfaces: >-
        {{
          network_interfaces | default([])
            + [item[0] | combine({'macaddress':item[1]})]
        }}
    loop: "{{ network_adapters | zip(macaddresses) }}"
```

outputs:

```json
{
  "macaddress": "00:50:56:9c:8c:b1",
  "name": "Network adapter one"
},
{
  "macaddress": "00:50:56:9c:8c:b2",
  "name": "Network adapter two"
}
```

Here are some of my tryouts, maybe someone finds it useful.

- add hash to the macaddresses list

  `"{{ macaddresses | json_query('[].{\"macaddress\": @}') }}"`

  ```json
  {
    "macaddress": "00:50:56:9c:8c:b1"
  },
  {
    "macaddress": "00:50:56:9c:8c:b2"
  }
  ```
- combine into a list of hashes

  `"{{ macaddresses | json_query('[].{\"macaddress\": @}') | zip(network_adapters) }}"`

  ```json
  [
    {
      "macaddress": "00:50:56:9c:8c:b1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Network adapter one"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "macaddress": "00:50:56:9c:8c:b2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Network adapter two"
    }
  ]
  ```
- combine into a dictionary

  `"{{ macaddresses | json_query('[].{\"macaddress\": @}') | map('combine', network_adapters) }}"`

  ```json
  {     
    "macaddress": "00:50:56:9c:8c:b1",
    "name": "Network adapter two"
  },
  {
    "macaddress": "00:50:56:9c:8c:b2",
    "name": "Network adapter two"
  }
  ```

I'm specially interested in the last one. This outputs dictionary with the last *network_adapters* item both times.
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(network_adapters|map(attribute='name')|zip(macaddresses))|
                 dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='macaddress') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - macaddress: 00:50:56:9c:8c:b1
    name: Network adapter one
  - macaddress: 00:50:56:9c:8c:b2
    name: Network adapter two
```

---

Q: *"**More complex data. Keep other attributes, like 'ip'?**"*

```yaml
    network_adapters:
    - name: "Network adapter one"
      ip: "192.168.0.1"
    - name: "Network adapter two"
      ip: "192.168.0.2"
```

A: No "one-liner", just the loop (you've already found out), e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        na2: "{{ na2|default([]) + [item.0|combine({'macaddress': item.1})] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ network_adapters }}"
        - "{{ macaddresses }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  na2:
  - ip: 192.168.0.1
    macaddress: 00:50:56:9c:8c:b1
    name: Network adapter one
  - ip: 192.168.0.2
    macaddress: 00:50:56:9c:8c:b2
    name: Network adapter two
```

Comment: Indeed. Thank you.

However only if first list has only single hashes.
Is it possible to achieve the same with more complex data?
```yaml
network_adapters:
- name: "Network adapter one"
  ip: "192.168.0.1"
- name: "Network adapter two"
  ip: "192.168.0.2"
```

Comment: `network_adapters: [{"name": "Network adapter one", "ip": "192.168.0.1"},{"name": "Network adapter two","ip": "192.168.0.2"}]`

Comment: The code should work as is. The first step is to 'map' the attribute 'name' anyway. Try it.

Comment: It does. I meant keeping other, like *ip*, attributes.

Comment: No one-liner. I've updated the answer. You might want to write a filter if needed e.g. for efficiency.